# Как правильно писать - безчиповый или бесчиповый?

Tags: приставка

как правильно писать - безчиповый или бесчиповый?

Answer (score 3):

Никогда не сталкивался с подобным словом в серьезных текстах, но однозначно - ***бесчиповый***. Приставка "без" (и "раз") перед глухими согласными пишется через С. исключений из этого правила нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Речь идет о платежных картах - платежная карта может быть с магнитной полосой и/или с чипом. Бесчиповая надежнее.

Comment: Неправильно - чиповая надежнее :))

Comment: Допустим. Хотя, я крепко сомневаюсь по всем параметрам. 
Магниная полоса легко копируется злоумышленниками - и просто быстро размагничивается. Но это к "пожарной охране, которую я представляю" отношения не имеет.

Важнее другое. "Бесчиповая" карта называется контактной, а "чиповая"- бесконтактной. Зачем термины плодить?

Comment: Не всегда чиповую карту можно считать бесконтактной. Чип может содержать, например, информацию о владельце, и устройство, использующее данную карту, может читать чип, но на чипе нет "бесконтактного" приложения. Технарям так понятнее, наверное, а с теми, кто владеет русским, не посоветовались. А я к ним и отношусь.

Comment: Вообще-то я именно технарь, более того, в прошлой жизни занимался изготовлением этих карт. Не в эмиссией в банке, а именно изготовлением - там, где эти карты делаются, от пластика до программирования и эмбоссирования. В те годы понятие "бесчиповый" не использовалось. Ну да ладно, понимаю, что я остал от жизни.